# Non-equal operator syntactic sugar on a nullable class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, operators, syntactic-sugar

I was checking up the Unity API documentation and stumbled upon this example code block:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;

    void Reset()
    {
        //Output the message to the Console
        Debug.Log("Reset");
        if (!target)
            target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }
}
```

What exactly '(!target)' means?

I thought it is the sugary way to write (target != null), but not quite sure because I had the understanding that this would always be false because null != false... What am I missing?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html

Comment: I believe it's a lay-over from the days of UnityScript (language based on javascript).

Comment: @Immersive no it's not ;) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html

Comment: @derHugo Oh, I'm aware of the 'how'.  I'm commenting more on the 'why'.

Comment: Well I'm only commenting on`it's a lay-over from the days of UnityScript`. Actually the `bool` comparison is faster and more secure than the `null` check. E.g. right after `Destroy(xy)` the result of `if(xy == null)` is not always "correct" while `if(xy)` surely behaves as expected ;) Unity's own example is quite stupid because it is not the same as a `null` check actually

Answer (score 2):

`MonoBehavior` inherits from `Behavior`, which inherits from `Component`, which inherits from [`Unity.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html). This is different than the C#/.NET provided `System.Object`.

In this class, there's an [implicit operator `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) from the `Object` type to a `bool`, which calls the `Object`'s internal base object comparison with itself and null as the operands. This ultimately checks if the object is still alive.

Since the type is implicitly convertible to a boolean, it can be used as a boolean expression in an `if` statement.

When the boolean conversion returns, the object you are checking for is still alive. When the boolean conversion returns `false`, the object you are checking for is no longer alive.

Comment: That's mostly correct though it doesn't replace a `!= null` check entirely. Actually you should never use a `!= null` for `Unity.Object` at all. It might fail in some cases because actually it is not exactly `null` but only equals a value of `null` while it keeps storing some information about e.g. the reason **why** it could be `null`. For that reason usually in Unity you don't get a `NullReferenceException` but a more explicit one like e.g. `MissingReferenceException` etc explaining Bette what possiby happened to the reference

Comment: Also `MonoBehaviour` does **not** inherit from `GameObject` but from `Behaviour` which inherits from `Component` which then inherits from `Object`! `GameObject` and `ScriptableObject` inherit directly from `Object` ;)

Comment: I felt so free adding some links to your answer ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to reflect the correct inheritance hierarchy and to be a bit more explicit with how it's comparing itself against null over a normal direct comparison.

Answer (score 0):

!target will be true when target is null

if we changed Target to the words HAS-OBJECT then the code is saying

```
if(NOT HAS-OBJECT)
{ 
 SET TO AN OBJECT
}
```

So in the code you posted, the !target is conditionally **true** when target is null

Comment: I would rather phrase it `if(not target exists)`